# Subsampling Scale Image View's method onImageLoaded() isn't being called

Tags: android, image

I'm using this library(https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) to display a huge image in my App. 
I need to know when the image is loaded, so i'm using this interface(https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/wiki/09.-Events), but this methods aren't being called by the system. The image is being loaded with no problems.

```
public class MapActivity extends BaseActivity implements SubsamplingScaleImageView.OnImageEventListener {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_map);

        imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.dayzmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onReady() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onImageLoaded() {
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewLoadError(Exception e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onImageLoadError(Exception e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTileLoadError(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="LOADING..."/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, you have not called `setOnImageEventListener()` on the `SubsamplingScaleImageView` to register your activity as the event listener.